# Spring: @Transactional annotation between HibernateTransactionManager and JpaTransactionManager

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-transactions

as you know spring transactions by default are **ReadOnly**, and to make them **ReadWrite** we just need to add the `@Transactionl` annotation to the service class or to the method where we will run update or create transactions.
However I realized, in the project I'm working on, the `@Transactional` annotation have no effect, I can't update or create entities and the reason I found was in the configuration file.
**old configuration:**

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
```

After changing it to this one it worked

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
```

Does anyone knows why using `JpaTransactionManager` make the `@Transactionl` annotation works fine, but using `HibernateTransactionManager` make the annotation have no effect?!

**UPDATED**
more details about the configuration:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
        https://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.x.y.as.*"/>
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.x.y.dao" entity-manager-factory-ref="sqlSessionFactory"/>

    <!-- Properties -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:/spring/database.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:/spring/as-server.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:/spring/database.user.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:/spring/as-server.user.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!--  Transaction Manager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Hibernate 5 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
    <bean id="sqlSessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.IsolationLevelDataSourceAdapter">
                <property name="targetDataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
                <property name="isolationLevel" value="2"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <array>
                <value>com.x.y.dao.entities</value>
                <value>com.x.y.dao.entities.admin</value>
                <value>com.x.y.dao.entities.misc</value>
                <value>com.x.y.dao.entities.publish</value>
                <value>com.x.y.impexp.dao</value>
            </array>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">scpas</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">${hibernate.generate_statistics}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- profiles -->
    <beans profile="debug">
        <import resource="debugContext.xml"/>
    </beans>

    <beans profile="cloudMT">
        <import resource="cloudMTContext.xml"/>
    </beans>

</beans>
```

I'm not using `<tx:annotation-driven />` instead I'm using this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class ApplicationConfig extends ResourceConfig {
...
}
```

Comment: Transactions aren't by default read-only, by default there is no transaction. Are you using plain hibernate or are you using JPA? If it is the latter you need the `JpaTransactionManager` not the `HibernateTransactionManager`. In short you have to use the proper tx manager for the technology in use.

Comment: I'm using Hibernate's session to run transactions

Comment: Then why is your question tagged with JPA? Also are you really using the session or are you unwrapping the `EntityManager` (as that still is JPA).

Comment: I'm using `SessionFActory.getSession()` from hibernate package, and that's the weird part why `@Transactional` annotation didn't work and after using `JpaTransactionManager` in the configuration it worked!

Comment: Are you using the correct `HibernateTransactionManager` for your version of Spring? Did you configure the `SessionFactory` or have you use the `LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean` to configure stuff? To fully answer your question and understand it, there basically is too little information.

Comment: how to know which hibernate version works with my spring? I'm using spring 5.2,
and I'm using LocalSessionFactoryBean
`<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">`

Comment: The fact that there is `hibernate5` in the package name should be an indicator of which version it is meant for.

Comment: I know but is it the right version?

Comment: If you are using hibernate 5 it is, but as stated there is important information missing in your question to give you a full insight. How are you configurating things, how did you enable transaction (you are still in XML so you need an `<tx:annotation-driven />` in there, how did you configure hibernate, there are many open endings here .

Comment: I have updated the question, please check it

Comment: A combination of XML and java config, why not do everything in java config? Anyway is there a `hibernate.properties` or `hibernate.cfg.xml` or hidden `persistence.xml` that adds to the configuration?

Comment: no that's it, I have pasted the whole configuration

Comment: But you are using JPA... That is what the `<jpa:repositories />` is about. And as of Hibernate 5.1 (Might be earlier) the `SessionFactory` extends `EntityManagerFactory`. So you are actually using JPA and do a fallback to Hibernate (unknowingly). But that is why the `JpaTransactionbManager` does work and the other doesn't.

Comment: I had to add `<jpa:repositories />` because @Repository annotation didn't work as well :p
actually this project is not fully spring it is using some spring packages that's why I had to adjust the configuration a bit to make some things works. is there an alternative for `<jpa:repositories />` in hibernate?

Comment: `@Repository` has nothing to do with transactions, and `<jpa:repositores />` is for Spring Data JPA repositories, if you use those you need it, if you don't then why is it even there. Addint `@Repository` to an interface doesn't do anything but hurt my eyes.

Comment: yes indeed I'm using spring data jpa and interface repositories that reduce a lot of boilerplate code so yeah I had to add it. so if I understand correctly from your explanation is that since I'm using `<jpa:repositores />` I will have to use `JpaTransactionManager` otherwise I can keep usin `HibernateTransactionManager` right?

Comment: Basically that is it. As you are using JPA (through Spring Data JPA) you need the `JpaTransactionManager`... If you were only using plain Hibernate the hibernate one would work, but as you aren't you need the other one.

Comment: just to let you know, I had to use `<jpa:repositores />` to inject repositories in services or controllers otherwise I get this exception NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type'X' available` where X is the interface with @Repository annotation on it and extends JpaRepository

Comment: as mentioned `@Repository` on an interface doesn't do anything especially not for Spring Data repositories (which is quite elaboratly explained in the respective documentation).

Comment: hmm weird, but in the documentation they mentioned that I need to add this annotation to mark this interface as repository so we can inject it and use it in other places!

Comment: That is for classes not for interfaces. If you have a class that is a repository (be it jdbc, jpa, plain hibernate, mongo or whaterver datastore you use) you need to use that annotation. It is, like `@Service` an specialized `@Component` annotation so componet-scanning can pick it up. `@Repository` has nothing to do with Spring Data. Spring Data has other means of finding interfaces that need to be available as repositories.

Comment: thanks for your time and explanation, enjoyed it a lot :)